# Case concept...Sql server query

Tags: sql-server

I was trying the below. My inner query works fine. But I get an error when I try the entire query. Please provide your inputs.

```
select 
   x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
   x.TestPlanName, 
   (case when x.ResultOutcome in ('Aborted','Error','Failed','Inconclusive','Timeout','Blocked') 
     then sum(count(x.ResultOutcome)) else 0
     as "Failed"  
     when x.ResultOutcome in ('Passed') 
     then sum(count(x.ResultOutcome)) else 0
     as "Passed" 
     when x.ResultOutcome in ('Not Executed') 
     then sum(count(x.ResultOutcome)) else 0
     as "Not Run"
     END
    )
from (select 
         TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
         TestPlanName,
         ResultOutcome, 
         count(*) as Total 
      from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
      where TestPlanName IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName, ResultOutcome
     ) x
order by TeamProjectProjectNodeName asc, TestPlanName asc
```

This is what i am getting from the inner query -

```
TeamProjectProjectNodeName  TestPlanName    ResultOutcome   Total
ACATS                       Test Automation Aborted            26
ACATS                       Test Automation Failed             61
```

This is the final Result format I am looking for -

```
TeamProjectProjectNodeName  TestPlanName    Failed  Passed    Not_Run
ACATS                       Test Automation 87     0        0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks...Surely I will take note of the pointers.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?  You cannot nest aggregates like you have in the outer query `sum(count())` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: TeamProjectProjectNodeName TestPlanName     ResultOutcome Total
ACATS                  Test Automation  Aborted 26
ACATS                  Test Automation  Failed          61 --Is what i am getting from the inner query

Comment: This is the format i am looking for -     TeamProjectProjectNodeName TestPlanName Failed Passed Test Not_Run                                                             ACATS                      Test Automation                               12      10     5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is invalid syntax to nest aggregates (i.e. (`sum(count))`).  Based on your existing query it seems that you are trying to pivot the data like the following:

```
select 
   x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
   x.TestPlanName, 
   sum(case when x.ResultOutcome in ('Aborted','Error','Failed','Inconclusive','Timeout','Blocked') then 1 else 0 end) as Failed,
   sum(case when x.ResultOutcome = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as Passed,
   sum(case when x.ResultOutcome = 'Not Executed' then 1 else 0 end) as NotRun
from 
(
   select 
       TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
       TestPlanName,
       ResultOutcome, 
       count(*) as Total 
   from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
   where TestPlanName IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName, ResultOutcome
) x
group by x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName, x.TestPlanName
order by TeamProjectProjectNodeName asc, TestPlanName asc;
```

You should be able to consolidate this code by using:

```
select 
   TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
   TestPlanName,
   sum(case when ResultOutcome in ('Aborted','Error','Failed','Inconclusive','Timeout','Blocked') then 1 else 0 end) as Failed,
   sum(case when ResultOutcome = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as Passed,
   sum(case when ResultOutcome = 'Not Executed' then 1 else 0 end) as NotRun
from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
where TestPlanName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName
order by TeamProjectProjectNodeName asc, TestPlanName asc;
```

Comment: ... and there were also some syntax errors related to the `CASE` (which were fixed in your answer).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Sql Server...trying to learn more from all possible hands-on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missing ends in your SQL. See a case statement below, with 2 cases...

```
    declare @test int
    set @test= 1

    select case when 2=@test then 'Is 2' else 

     case when @test = 3 then 'Is 3' else @test end  end
```